# Problem with implementation method Get IEEE 754 Format, when parameter is double and return type should be string

Tags: c#, .net, string, double, ieee-754

```
public static string GetIEEE754Format(this double number)
{
    return number.ToString();
}
```

Is it an easy way to implement this method ? Can someone explain how to implement this function in C# code ?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to convert a `double` to `string` in this context. Read my asnwer below for more info.

Answer (score 1):

IEEE 754 is not related at all to the string representation of a floating point number, but rather to the binary representation. Therefore it doesn't make sense to convert a `double` to `string` in this context.

For example if your floating type is `double` (as in your example), the IEEE 754 standard specifies that the 8 bytes that are required to represent it have the following structure:

1. The first bit holds the **sign**.
2. Next 11 bits hold the **exponent** (offseted by -1023 to be precise).
3. Next 52 bits hold the **mantisa**.

The value of such a variable is:

```
 (-1)^(sign) * (1.<mantisa>) * 2^(<exponent>-1023)
```

Altogether it's 64 bits that correspond to those 8 bytes.
Any `double` variable has this structure already (in a system using IEEE 754, which is very common).

A similar defintion exists in the IEEE 754 standard for 32 bits `float` values.

You can see more info here: [IEEE 754 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

Answer (score 0):

In docuentation You have method to convert data types to bytes.

```cs
/**
* Converts a floating point number to a string with the same bytes
* @param number The double to convert
* @returns A string containing the same bytes as the double
*/
public static string GetIEEE754Format(this double number)
{
    // Converts double -> Int64 -> byte[] -> string
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(DoubleToInt64Bits(number)));
}
```

> See:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.doubletoint64bits?view=net-6.0

Comment: Instead of just saying there's a method and linking to it, can you [edit] your answer to state what the method is called and, ideally, including an example of how to use it? That would make this a more useful answer. As is, it relies too heavily on a link, and doesn't actually state what the answer is. (Though one can infer it from the URL.)